# Having trouble with a custom adapter factory not being loaded

Tags: osgi, aem, sling

we're having a bit of trouble getting a custom adapter factory loaded in CQ5. The adapter factory code works fine, as the trouble is that we are attempting to use it during the @Activate phase in another SlingServlet.

It seems as though when the Activate phase is called within the Sling Servlet, the Custom Adapter Factory class has not yet been loaded in.

Is there a way to specify dependancy upon the other bundle having loaded, or is it generally a bad idea to attempt to use an Adaptable inside an activate function.

Comment: I think it is at least not a very good idea to do this. As the AdapterFactory isn't referenced directly but registered for the adaptTo from source to target class. So I don't think you'll know if the factory is available on activate of your servlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right - the adapter factory starts after the servlet and it isn't available during the servlet activation. Normally such cases are solved by OSGi dependency management, but we don't have a clear dependency here, as the servlet doesn't `@Reference` the adapter factory, but it's used via a Sling adapter factory manager.

You have three options:

1. Reference the adapter factory in servlet to create an aritficial, *strong* dependency between two components:

   ```
   @Reference(target = "(component.name=your.adapter.factory.package.name)")
   ```
2. If the servlet and the adapter factory are placed in different bundles, you may use [startlevels](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/startlevel/package-summary.html) to control the order of bundles activation. You can control the startlevel by putting OSGi bundles into following JCR directory:

   ```
   /apps/[app]/install/[startLevel]
   ```
3. Extract the logic from adapter factory and use it directly in the servlet activator, without the `adaptTo()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Tomek. It's confirmed my suspicions.